# Login screen design / wallpaper does not work

Tags: xubuntu, login, screen, lightdm, gdm

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 but installed xubuntu-desktop afterwards.

Now the login screen is very ugly:

- The theme is not applied and I cannot change the background picture (only black one shown)
- Only a grey login-box for username / password is displayed

Can you hint me how to solve this?

- Is there a way to take a screenshot of the login-screen so I can show
  what is wrong?
- I am not even sure which system is used for login - GDM or lightdm - how can I find out?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change my background image by the following:
 
`sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`
 
Then add:
 
`background=/full/path/to/your/photo.png`
 
(It has to be png format.)